# Android: простой способ чередовать элементы UI в одном месте

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ui

Есть диалог, в одном месте которого нужно в зависимости от ситуации показывать то один элемент, то другой. Пример:

[image: Виден один элемент]
[image: Виден второй элемент]

Хочется сделать это так, чтобы остальные элементы не съезжали. Чтобы область которую занимают чередующиеся элементы была постоянного размера.

Как это проще всего сделать?

Можно конечно вручную менять видимость, но тогда при переключении, если будет разная высотая то нижележащие элементы будут скакать. Можно вручную выставить их одной высоты, но это неудобно. Нужно будет каждый раз исправлять высоты всех чередующихся элементов, после того как я изменю один из них.

Например в Qt есть Stack Layout, который позволяет чередовать элементы и при этом принимает размер максимального из них. Есть ли в Android что-нибудь подобное?

Comment: FrameLayout меняйте видимость дочерних элементов, ничего "скакать" не будет

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл подходящий элемент: [ViewSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher). Он как раз именно для этого и предназначен, чтобы переключатся между двумя элементами. И высота у него равна высоте максимального элемента.

Ещё есть [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) если нужно переключать больше чем два элемента.